# 403 Error with Zend Framework 1.XX trying to load Fonts

Tags: php, zend-framework, fonts

I have the following public structure in my application:

public

- css
- images
- javascript
- fonts

I also have this in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css|ttf|svg|eot|woff)$ index.php
```

In the application CSS, JS and Image files work as expected and will not go through the autoloader. I assume this is due to the rewrite rule above.

BUT

I have just downloaded a SocialIcon pack and i've saved this to /fonts. In my CSS i use this to load the font files in:

```
src: url('/fonts/socicon-1.3/socicon.eot');
```

(note: followed an example by the developer to get this working in my CSS)

The file exists, has the same permissions as everything else and the eot file has been ignored with the rewrite rule.

But when i try to use the new fonts i get a 403 error. Apparently example.com/fonts/socicon-1.3/socicon.eot doesnt exist when it does. I'm thinking i might have some issues with Zend doing something with Fonts?

Can anyone suggest how i fix this permission error?

Answer (score 0):

Holy Smokes!

I'm a little silly. Seems the issue was actually a 403. I had the wrong permissions on the Folder. So i chmod 775 and it works.

Unless 775 isnt the best one?